# Actionscript Convert String to Int

Tags: string, actionscript, int

I am using Actionscript 2.0

In a Brand new Scene.  My only bit of code is:

```
    trace(int('04755'));
    trace(int('04812'));
```

Results in:

- 2541
- 4812

Any idea what I am doing wrong/silly?

By the way, I am getting this source number from XML, where it already has the leading 0.  Also, this works perfect in Actionscript 3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Converting a string with a leading 0 to a Number in ActionScript 2 assumes that the number you want is **octal**. Give this function I've made for you a try:

```
var val:String = '00010';

function parse(str:String):Number
{
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
    {
        var c:String = str.charAt(i);
        if(c != "0") break;
    }

    return Number(str.substr(i));
}

trace(parse(val)); // 10
trace(parse(val) + 10); // 20
```

Basically what you want to do now is just wrap your string in the above `parse()` function, instead of `int()` or `Number()` as you would typically.

Comment: Thanks for this function, worked great! I assumed that's what this was doing, but this code saved me a lot of time heh

Answer (score 30):

In AS3, you can try:

```
parseInt('04755', 10)
```

10 above is the **radix**.

Comment: Upvoted because this seems like a better approach than string manipulation to strip leading 0's, should also work in AS2 according to docos

Comment: Like how I answered this 2 months earlier but my answer was ignored! Nice!

Comment: @NickWiggill They key the distinguishes this answer from yours is Rahul has used the radix argument which yours was lacking. I also have no idea why I was so naive as to provide my existing answer but alas (I guess it was 3 years ago).

Answer (score 18):

```
parseInt(yourString);
```

...is the correct answer. [`.parseInt()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#parseInt%28%29) is a top-level function.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a simple one...

try this -

```
temp="120";
temp2="140";
temp3=int ( temp );
temp4=int ( temp2 );
temp5=temp4+temp3;
trace(temp5);
```

so, all you need is...

```
int("190");
```